# Error with setenv: startup.m file "does not exist or is unreadable" on MATLAB

Tags: macos, matlab

I am using some MATLAB package for work and when setting up I keep running into this issue. In the package instructions, it was asked to define the environment variable  to point to the reference data files I am using in the scripts. So, I created a startup.m file in the directory of package, like the instructions indicated, where I wrote:

```
setenv('DIR_MODELS_REF_DAT', '</Users/username/Downloads/package/dat/iri2016>')
addpath /Users/username/Downloads/package/dat/iri2016
```

Where dat/iri2016 is where my data file exists for the script I am running, saved this and reloaded MATLAB and ran the script again. Now it keeps giving me the error message:

`Reference data file, </Users/username/Downloads/package/dat>/iri2016/igrf2015.dat, does not exist or is unreadable. Check that the environment variable DIR_MODELS_REF_DAT is set to the directory containing the reference data.`

I don't know how many times I should reload my MATLAB for the path to be fully included.

I am running this on MATLAB_R2020b on a mac os machine.

Comment: Leave out the `<` and `>` from that variable definition. It is using all of the string "`</Users/username/Downloads/package/dat/iri2016>`" as a path, but it's not a legal path.

Comment: Can you copy MATLAB package file to directory where you setup your MATLAB?

Comment: I tried leaving out < and > but it didn't work so I changed the MATLAB package file like @Fatih asked and now it's giving me a different error: "Environment variable DIR_MODELS_REF_DAT is not set" but I have a startup file inside the package file that says: "setenv('DIR_MODELS_REF_DAT', '/Users/username/Documents/MATLAB/package/dat/iri2016')" should I move the startup file to the MATLAB directory instead of package directory? and is the path to the data file correct?

Comment: when I do " value = getenv('DIR_MODELS_REF_DAT')"  it gives back an empty array "value =

  0×0 empty char array"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see `<...>` brackets in a value definition or example like that, it generally means "replace this with the actual value appropriate for your environment", instead of using literal `<...>` brackets in the value. So instead of this:

```matlab
setenv('DIR_MODELS_REF_DAT', '</Users/username/Downloads/package/dat/iri2016>')
```

You should use something like this:

```matlab
setenv('DIR_MODELS_REF_DAT', '/Users/username/Downloads/package/dat/iri2016')
```

And you should replace that "username" with your actual username; e.g. if your username is "jamie", it should be:

```matlab
setenv('DIR_MODELS_REF_DAT', '/Users/jamie/Downloads/package/dat/iri2016')
```

A nicer way to do this is to just query your home directory using `getenv`:

```matlab
setenv('DIR_MODELS_REF_DAT', [getenv('HOME') '/Downloads/package/dat/iri2016'])
```

That way you don't have to modify the code when it's run as a different user.

Can you tell us exactly what Matlab package you're using here?

Comment: It is a toolbox called pharlap and thanks this actually helps!